# Exclamation mark in folder for webpack

Tags: webpack

Is it possible to use webpack, when a parent folder has an exclamation mark?

This is kind of an update question, because [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5320) is years old, and webpack had at least one major version update since.

I know, that an exclamation mark is used for webpack's inline loader syntax, but

- The errors given are about the cache and output folder, where that syntax doesn't apply anyways afaik. It almost looks like the related check for exclamation marks, which got added to the test for absolute paths, was forgotten, and as both cache and output are marked as absolute paths in the schema, the error happens.
- I don't use that syntax ever, can't i somehow disable it, and allow the exclamation mark?
- Can't the exclamation mark somehow be escaped, to note to webpack, that it's not loader syntax?
- Can't webpack remember it as "no, this is a normal path, and no special loader syntax"?

It just sounds so weird, that "you can't use webpack, if your folder has an exclamation mark in it", which is otherwise a valid folder name, on both windows/linux.

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "C:\!ohnoes\project\.cache" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
>   -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
> - configuration.output.path: The provided value "C:\!ohnoes\project\dist" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
>   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).

PS: "Just remove the exclamation mark" isn't always so simple. Explaining to someone, that their otherwise normal folder name is not acceptable, is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I tried symbol link, but webpack will resolve it to the real path.

`subst` works.